# Distribution of numbers with limited information

Tags: probability, matrices

I have a question regarding the ability to accurately predict the organization of numbers within a space. The specific example is as follows:

Consider a square that is divided equally into 9 smaller squares like the face of a Rubik’s cube.  Each smaller square is designated by row # (R) and column # (C), such that the middlemost square would be R2, C2. For example, consider a distribution of numbers as follows: R1, C1 = 3; R1, C2 = 1; R1, C3 = 2; R2, C1 = 2; R2, C2 =1; R2, C3 = 3; R3, C1 = 0; R3, C2 = 1, R3, C3 = 2. If we only know the sum of the numbers within each row and column, i.e. Sum total of Row 1= 6, Row 2 = 6, Row 3 = 3, Column 1 = 5, Column 2= 3, Column 3 = 7, can we determine the original distribution of numbers across the entire space? So far by using random examples, as listed above, I can only come up with the possible states, with some information of the limits dictated by the minimum sum total of each Row or Column. This seems like a Sudoku problem, but with no hints! Any sort of solution/feedback/guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally not.  You have six equations in nine unknowns and one of them is redundant because the sum of all the rows equals the sum of all the columns equals the sum of all the numbers.  Normally you can choose four of the numbers (but not in the same row) to be anything you want, then solve for the rest.  If you restrict the entries in some way, you may be able to find a solution.  For example, if all the entries are naturals from $1$ to $9$ and the sums are $27$, you know all the entries are $9$.  If you know all the entries are distinct naturals from $1$ to $9$, you may be able to find a solution using that.